# How to delete specific question version that included my privacy due my mistake?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

How to delete specific question version that included my privacy due my mistake?

[Some documentation for the "ext4-rsv-conver" process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463210/some-documentation-for-the-ext4-rsv-conver-process)
I want to delete [the version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/463210/1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I started the redaction; it's pending now waiting for another mod to approve it, but it should be done soon.

If this happens again in the future, you can flag the post for mod attention and explain what you need in the flag message.